# One too many loops with vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a report from multiple sheets. My first sheet is a list of customers (name, address, route, etc), no duplicates. I have a separate list of items belonging to customers (customer 1, item 1; customer 1, item 2, etc) and I'm loop through the item list and copy the contents of columns 2, 3, and 4 where the current customer name is in column A.

Once exhausted, I want to move to the next customer on the customer list and loop through again selecting the items that belong to that customer.  My outer for statement works, but my inner one is not proper.  I've tried a few variations with no luck.  Here's my sub...

```
Sub BuildReport()
    Dim clRng As Range
    Dim itemRng As Range
    Dim clRow As Range
    Dim itemRow As Range
    Dim currentItemRow As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long

    Set clRng = wsCustomerList.Range("A1:A" & LastRow(wsCustomerList))
    Set itemRng = wsItemInfo.Range("A2:A" & LastRow(wsItemInfo))

    i = 2
    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 2

    For Each clRow In clRng.Rows
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,1,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,2,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,3,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,4,FALSE)&"", ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,5,FALSE)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,6,FALSE))"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 2).Value = "Start Date:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,7,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 3).Value = "Terms:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,8,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 4).Value = "Route:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,9,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 5).Value = "Delivery Days:"
        'wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Orders,2,FALSE)=1 then M else 0)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 6).Value = "Item Code:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("B" & i + 6).Value = "Item Desc.:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("C" & i + 6).Value = "Inventory:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 6).Value = "Minimum:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 6).Value = "Current Price:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("F" & i + 6).Value = "Last Increase:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("G" & i + 6).Value = "Previous Price:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 6 & ":G" & i + 6).Font.Bold = True

        For Each itemRow In itemRng.Rows
            l = LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard) + 1
            currentItemRow = itemRow
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & l).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & k & "C1,Items,2,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & l).Font.Bold = False
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("B" & l).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & k & "C1,Items,3,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & l).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & k & "C1,Items,4,FALSE)"
            'l = LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard) + 1
            'k = k + 1
        Next itemRow
        i = LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard) + 1
        j = j + 1
    Next clRow

End Sub
```

Comment: We could use a little more context to provide a good answer.  One problem is that your loop `Do While itemRow = currentItemRow`.  You modify neither `itemRow` nor `currentItemRow` in your loop, so the condition always evaluates `True` and it's looping infinitely.  In general, you can use nested `For` loops that go over every row in the item list for each customer and, if the customer names match, copy the desired cell values.  For loops handle your increments for you.

Comment: edited my original post.

Comment: Now your edit doesn't make sense as you make no use of `clrow` in your loop.

Comment: Use `Set currentItemRow = itemRow` in your second loop.

Comment: Made the change @PeterT, however each iteration is listing the same item over and over again.  It's not progressing to the next row.  I guess I need it to check the customer name in each row as it loops the items and if match the copy, else exit and start at the top with the next customer.  If I uncomment k= k + 1 I get the item and price from the next customer, which I understand, I just don't understand how to loop this using the same customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I've solved my problem!  I let it run and it took a little over two hours.  Not sure if I can optimize but I'm happy it's working. Anyway here's my solution for anyone who's interested.  Thanks for the help.

```
Sub BuildReport()
    Dim customerRng As Range
    Dim customerRow As Range
    Dim itemRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long

    Set customerRng = wsCustomerList.Range("A1:A" & LastRow(wsCustomerList))

    i = 2
    j = 1
    l = 8

    For Each customerRow In customerRng.Rows
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,1,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,2,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,3,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,4,FALSE)&"", ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,5,FALSE)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,6,FALSE))"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 2).Value = "Start Date:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,7,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 3).Value = "Terms:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,8,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 4).Value = "Route:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,9,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 5).Value = "Delivery Days:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Orders,18,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 6).Value = "Item Code:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("B" & i + 6).Value = "Item Desc.:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("C" & i + 6).Value = "Inventory:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("D" & i + 6).Value = "Minimum:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 6).Value = "Current Price:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("F" & i + 6).Value = "Last Increase:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("G" & i + 6).Value = "Previous Price:"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & i + 2 & ":E" & i + 5).Font.Bold = True
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & i + 6 & ":G" & i + 6).Font.Bold = True

    Set itemRng = wsItemInfo.Range("A2:A" & LastRow(wsItemInfo))

    For k = 1 To LastRow(wsItemInfo)
        'If wsItemInfo.Cells(k, 1) = customerRow Then
         Do While wsItemInfo.Cells(k, 1) = customerRow
            wsItemInfo.Cells(k, 2).Copy
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A" & LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard) + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsItemInfo.Cells(k, 3).Copy
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("B" & LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard, "B") + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsItemInfo.Cells(k, 4).Copy
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E" & LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard, "E") + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            k = k + 1
        Loop
        'End If
    Next k

    j = j + 1
    i = LastRow(wsCustomerReportCard) + 1

    Next customerRow

    MsgBox "And we're done!"

End Sub
```